# Save content of member of struct to variable

Tags: c

Sorry, but I'm relative newby to C.
I have a struct which contains registers. At a specific point in the program I would like to save the content of some specific registers to a variable. It looks like:

```
typedef struct Register   // Struct with the registers
{

   uint32 REG1;                       
   uint32 REG2;            
   uint32 REG3;            
   uint32 REG4;            

} Register_t;

Register_t *pToRegister_t;  // Pointer to the struct

uint32 contentREG1;
uint32 contentREG2;

contentREG1 = (*pToRegister_t).REG1   // in contentREG1 I need to store the value of REG1
contentREG2 = (*pToRegister_t).REG2   // in contentREG1 I need to store the value of REG1
```

As values I get the addresses, like 0xFFFFFFFF, 0xFFFFFFFF. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is `uint32` etc? Use standard types where available! And don't use `_t` suffix. It is reserved by some platforms, e.g. POSIX.

Comment: Where do you initialize the pointer, and the struct it points to? Btw, why `(*foo).bar` instead of `foo->bar`?

Comment: you can't dereference pointer which doesn't point to valid object

Comment: @Olaf: Sorry, forgot to describe it: uint32 is an unsigned integer on 32 bit platform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume, for sake of discussion, that `uint32` is an unsigned integral type.

Defining a pointer does not create instance of the `struct`.   So you need to create an instance for the pointer to point at, and explicitly initialise the pointer so it does.

```
typedef struct Register   // Struct with the registers
{

   uint32 REG1;                       
   uint32 REG2;            
   uint32 REG3;            
   uint32 REG4;            

} Register_t;

int main()
{
     Register_t *pToRegister_t;  // Pointer to the struct

     Register_t thing = {1U, 2U, 3U, 4U};

     uint32 contentREG1;
     uint32 contentREG2;
     uint32 contentREG3;

     pToRegister_t = &thing;   //   make the pointer point at a valid instance

     contentREG1 = (*pToRegister_t).REG1;    // access thing.REG1   
     contentREG2 = pToRegister_t->REG2;      // alternative - access thing.REG2
     contentREG3 = thing.REG3;

}
```

Failure to initialise the pointer (i.e. not making it point at a valid iobject) means all attempts to use the members via the pointer will yield undefined behaviour.